# *** stack smashing detected *** because of 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

```cpp
   char m[2];
    vector< vector<tuple<long int, long int>> > f(3);
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
      scanf("%s %ld %ld", m, &n, &c);
      if(m[0]=='1'){                                        //f--> 1
          f[m[1]-65].push_back(make_tuple(c, n));  //turn ascii to number
          m1+=cost;
      }
     ..... //irelevant to f
    }
```

I am having this piece of code and I am facing this problem :
f is supposed to be a 2d-vector of vectors of tuples.
I know I need 3 rows in `f` but I don't know the numbers of elements in each row (that's why I have a vector).
I thought that putting that 3 defines that I want 3 rows. But it seems like something is wrong : when I have testcase where f[0] or f[1] or f[2] has to hold more than two elements I am getting this error message :  `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated Aborted (core dumped)`.

If in the other hand I remove, that 3 completely : `vector< vector<tuple<long int, long int>> > f` I am getting a seg fault and I suppose it has to do with the fact that I am accessing with `f[m[1]-65]` a row that does not yet exist?

So the thing is , I need to be able to seperate my input according to `m` and I know that `m[0] = {1,2,3}` so I am using that to get `m[0] - 65 = {0,1,2}` as indexes and fill those 3 vectors. Can you help me get through this?

Comment: The array `m` will only be able to hold a **one**-character null-terminated string.

Comment: By the way, please try to avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by the value `65` you mean the ASCII encoded value for the character `'A'`, then use the actual character `'A'` instead. Also note that this isn't portable, and that it will fail if the input isn't an upper-case (ASCII) character.

Comment: You cannot index into a vector if you haven't already grown the vector to that size.  In your case, `f` is empty but you are indexing into it, which is out of bounds and undefined behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you for your advice, I will change it to 'A'. I know that is going to be 'A','B', or 'C' for sure that's why I am using it ++ thanks for the point abut null I forgot this

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis it seems though that it works , i printed the elements . But it won't work for more that two. If i want to put them in these indexes isn't there a workaround?

Comment: "Seems to work" in undefined behavior contexts really is dangerous.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis But `f` it created with the size `3`.

Comment: @brucebanner If you know the size will always be `3`, then why not use an array? Like `std::array<std::vector<...>, 3> f;`?

Comment: fair, but `f[m[1]-65]` is using unvalidated user-provided input, and does not in any way guarantee that f is accessed with a valid index.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well that could be the case